# Extracting email addresses in an html block in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, html-parsing, email

I am creating a parser that wards off against spamming and harvesting of emails from a block of text that comes from tinyMCE (so it may or may not have html tags in it)

I've tried regexes and so far this has been successful:

```
/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i
```

problem is, i need to ignore all email addresses with mailto hrefs. for example:

```
<a href="mailto:test@mail.com">test@mail.com</a>
```

should only return the second email add.

To get a background of what im doing, im reversing the email addresses in a block so the above example would look like this:

```
<a href="mailto:test@mail.com">moc.liam@tset</a>
```

problem with my current regex is that it also replaces the one in href. Is there a way for me to do this with a single regex? Or do i have to check for one then the other? Is there a way for me to do this just by using gsub or do I have to use some nokogiri/hpricot magicks and whatnot to parse the mailtos? Thanks in advance!

Here were my references btw:

so.com/questions/504860/extract-email-addresses-from-a-block-of-text

so.com/questions/1376149/regexp-for-extracting-a-mailto-address

im also testing using this:

http://rubular.com/

*edit*

here's my current helper code:

```
def email_obfuscator(text)
  text.gsub(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i) { |m|
    m = "<span class='anti-spam'>#{m.reverse}</span>"
  }
end
```

which results in this:

```
<a target="_self" href="mailto:<span class='anti-spam'>moc.liamg@tset</span>"><span class="anti-spam">moc.liamg@tset</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option if lookbehind doesn't work:

`/\b(mailto:)?([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})\b/i`

This would match all emails, then you can manually check if first captured group is "mailto:" then skip this match.

Comment: it works using rubular, but just another question, how do i check if the first captured group is mailto? I'll pass it to the function again?

here is my current code for the obfuscator: (see above)

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Ruby. Usually when you do a regexp search it will return you an array of matched elements, which are split into captured groups.

Comment: I researched on that too but then again, you will have to know which group to pick. What im trying to aim at here is to 'replace on the fly', where something like this could happen:

1. start parsing the block of text
2. oh i see an email address, lemme invert that.
3. oh i see another email address, but then this one has a mailto: before it, it must be a hyperlink. move on.
4. i see an email again, this time with no mailto:, invert it again.
5. back to step 2

and so on.

Comment: So do you have an ability to check every matched email and act differently based on what it contains?

Comment: i think so. does that mean each email i get should be checked against another regex? or maybe i can do a regex that returns an email address or an email address with a mailto: appended. then make an if statement that should decide whether or not to reverse it?

Comment: I think this is what you have been suggesting yesterday and i kinda got lost(maybe because I have been at it for hours). I just got back on this today and I tried your regex then having an if-else statement that checks if the string has a mailto: and voila! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
/\b(?<!mailto:)[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i
```

The `(?<!mailto:)` is a negative lookbehind, which will ignore any matches starting with `mailto:`

I don't have Ruby set up at work, unfortunately, but it worked with PHP when I tested it...

Comment: i tried it using rubular but it says 

Undefined (?...) sequence.

i think the < is the culprit. what does it stand for again?

Comment: Hmm, looks like Ruby doesn't support lookbehind according to http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UJ - that's annoying.

The ?<! means that the string you're matching (the email address) mustn't be preceded by the lookbehind string (mailto:) in order for the match to succeed. In this case you'd probably be best off with serg555's suggestion.

Comment: i'd up this since it is also helpful but i don't have the right priveleges. anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store all the matched emails in an array and [remove any duplicates](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000747)? You can do this easily with the ruby standard library and (I imagine) it's probably quicker/more maintainable than adding more complexity to your regex.

```
emails = ["email_one@example.com", "email_one@example.com", "email_two@example.com"]
emails.uniq # => ["email_one@example.com", "email_two@example.com"]
```

Comment: As said in the function above, i will just replace the emails with their inverted counterparts, meaning if i put them in an array i will have to remember from what part of the text blog i got them from.